# Как понять рекурсию Common Lisp?

Tags: рекурсия, lisp

Вот сама функция копирования списка:

```
(defun my-copy-list (lst)
   (if (atom lst)
       lst
       (cons (car lst) (my-copy-list (cdr lst)))))
```

A **trace** выдает мне такой код:

```
 CL-USER> (our-copy-list '(a b c))                                                 
| 7  0: (OUR-COPY-LIST (A B C))                                                      
| 8    1: (OUR-COPY-LIST (B C))                                                      
| 9      2: (OUR-COPY-LIST (C))                                                      
|10        3: (OUR-COPY-LIST NIL)                                                    
|11        3: OUR-COPY-LIST returned NIL                                             
|12      2: OUR-COPY-LIST returned (C)                                               
|13    1: OUR-COPY-LIST returned (B C)                                               
|14  0: OUR-COPY-LIST returned (A B C)                                               
|15(A B C)
```

Правильно ли я понял? Cписок уменьшается на один элемент спомощью **cdr**, затем сработало условие **if (atom lst)** - функция встретила **nil** и вернула его в качестве значения. После этого шага, я не понимаю. Как здесь работает **cons**? Она берет **car lst**, но **trace** показывает, что список начинает наращиватся с последнего элемента!

Answer (score 2):

> но trace показывает, что список начинает наращиватся с последнего элемента!

`trace` в этом случае сначала показывает внутренние вызовы функции, а потом внешние. То есть в обратном порядке по сравнению с тем, как они вызывались.

Давайте по шагам рассмотрим, что здесь происходит. Я буду использовать номера от 7 до 14 из вашего результата `trace`, так как они очень удобные.

В строке 7 самое начало — мы вызвали функцию:

```lisp
(our-copy-list '(a b c))
```

В строке 8 функция из строки 7 вызвала cons, но в качестве второго аргумента вызвала себя же (но с другим аргументом). Мы сначала рассчитываем внутреннюю функцию (так как мы не можем сделать cons, пока не узнаем, что именно будет cons'ить, а для этого надо посчитать внутреннюю функцию).

Поэтому Лисп откладывает `cons` где-то в памяти в стеке, а переходит к рассмотрению внутреннней функции `our-copy-list`:

```
(cons 'a (our-copy-list '(b c)))
```

В строке 9 уже внутренняя функция вызвала ещё более глубокую функцию. (`trace` подсказывает нам, что это второй уровень вложенности, числом `2:`). Так что внутренний `cons` тоже записываем в памяти, а всё внимание сосредатачиваем на внутреннем `our-copy-list`:

```
(cons 'a 
      (cons 'b (our-copy-list '(c))))
```

И эта вложенная функция снова сделала то же самое — вызвала себя же. Это видно в строке 10. Снова запоминаем cons'ы в стеке (сейчас у нас там запомнено три cons'а) и всё внимание обращаем на `our-copy-list`:

```
(cons 'a 
      (cons 'b
            (cons 'c (our-copy-list NIL))))
```

А вот здесь, на строке 11, `(our-copy-list NIL)` наконец-то вернёт значение! Им будет nil. Мы можем подставить его в `cons`:

```
(cons 'a 
      (cons 'b
            (cons 'c NIL)))
```

Теперь мы знаем, что вернёт внутренний `(cons 'c NIL)` — он вернёт список из одного элемента, символа `c`. Условно я обозначу его в схеме `'(c)` — но тут есть подвох. Список, созданный с помощью `(cons 'c NIL)` можно изменять — это нам обещает стандарт Лиспа. А вот про список `'(c)` таких обещаний нам стандарт никто не даёт.

Но для простоты напишем `'(c)`.

Итак, в строке 12 мы уже знаем результат `(cons 'c NIL)`:

```
(cons 'a 
      (cons 'b '(c)))
```

Теперь в строке 13 мы можем посчитать `(cons 'b '(c))` (он будет равен списку, примерно равному `'(b c)`, но, в отличие от `'(b c)`, стандарт даёт право его изменять) и подставить его во внешнюю функцию:

```
(cons 'a '(b c))
```

И вот наконец на строке 14 мы можем посчитать значение самого первого cons'а:

```
'(a b c)
```

Это и будет наш результат (с поправкой на то, что `'(a b c)` — это условное обозначение: новосозданный список можно изменять, а вот как будет работать `'(a b c)` при изменении — никто не гарантирует, зависит от реализации).

Comment: Большое спасибо! Самое понятное обьяснение процесса, которое я встречал! И уловил суть. Еще раз спасибо!